# Wordpress Rest API

Tags: javascript, api, wp-api

I'm trying to call a post from a Wordpress install using WP REST API.   I keep getting an error in return and I can't find out why.  Do I need to authenticate?   One website said I don't need to authenticate for a GET request.   WP REST API: Version 2.0-beta9. Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

setTimeout(GetPosts, 2000);

function GetPosts() {

     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://easterly.haamap.com/wp-json/posts',
        data: {
            filter: {
            'posts_per_page': 1
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

}

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of the REST API are you using? If you're using the version that's bundled with WordPress 4.4 (ie, v2), you'll need to change your `url` to something like `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`.

### Reference

[WP API version 2 docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/)

Comment: I've tried that I still get the error.  Is there a way to retrieve the error code?

Comment: What happens if you use `console.log( 'error' );` when you get an error? When I try to `GET` a bogus REST URL, it gives me back a JSON object along these lines: `{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}` (which is basically a JSONified `WP_Error` object).

Comment: yes, I get 'error'.  The Network shows a 404 for that url.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/212749/edit) to indicate what version of the REST API you're using (v1, v2, or the version bundled with WordPress 4.4)? Thanks.

Comment: Version 2.0-beta9

Comment: Maybe I need to include a file or Wordpress tag in my header?

Comment: The whole point to the API is to be able to use WordPress content w/o needing to load all of WordPress. Presumably you have a WordPress site at `http://easterly.haamap.com/` that you're trying to pull data from -- correct?

Comment: Yes, but my wordpress is installed below the main directory...so really it's http://easterly.haamap.com/wordpress, but when I try http://easterly.haamap.com/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts I still get a 404 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33376/discussion-between-pat-j-and-the-hawk).

Comment: [This](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) is the updated WP REST API V2 reference.

Comment: Thanks, @Brethlosze, I've updated the URL in the answer.